# Virtual camera in android for skype

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, video-capture, video-processing

I have created a **DirectShow** filter and an **ffmpeg** based application which enables me to register a virtual camera, read a USB camera's feed, add some effects to it and then write that edited stream to the virtual camera. Skype can now view this virtual camera and stream it like other webcams.

Now I need to achieve the same on **android**. I have to read the mobile camera's stream, edit it and then send it to skype. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: I am searching for it too... Maybe this requires a rooted device...